# Is the Accept an answer feature available?

Tags: support

Am still new to the StackExchange community. I noticed there was an accept an answer functionality in StackOverflow. Is it available here? If yes, where is it found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "accept answer" functionality exists globally on all Stack Exchange sites, Unix&Linux included.  It also exists on all the meta sites.

It's a fundamental part of the Stack Exchange Question/Answer format and infrastructure, and is definitely available here (and on ever other Stack Exchange site/community that is launched). You can accept answers **to questions you have asked** by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer:

[image]

This is explained in the relevant [Help Center page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101) on the network's meta.

Keep in mind that every Stack Exchange site runs the same software as Stack Overflow does.  It's the same software, just a different 'community' and 'focus' to the site than Stack Overflow has (here on Unix&Linux specifically, the focus is to serve Unix & Linux users and to provide them a place to ask questions that are on topic per the Help Center's [On-Topic Question Topics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and to get relevant answers to those questions).

Comment: thanks. Seems the question in my case was answered under comments so technically there was no answer (under answers section)

Comment: @Arden In the case that your question is answered as a comment: It is generally acceptable to ask the Commenter with the correct answer to turn his comment into an answer, and then you Accept the Answer

Comment: @Thomas thanks alot for the clarification